# Converting String! to String

Tags: swift

I have a Swift app with a view that has a text field and a button.  When the button is clicked, it invokes the method below.

```
@IBAction func AddClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    employeeManager.AddFirstName(firstName.text)
}
```

I'm not sure why I keep getting the following error:

```
Cannot invoke 'AddFirstName' with an argument list of type '(String!)'
```

Is it because I cannot implicitly convert type `String!` to `String`?

AddClick definition:

```
var employeeManager: EmployeeManager = EmployeeManager()

class EmployeeManager {

    func AddFirstName(firstName: String){}
```

Even if I change the code to

```
func AddFirstName(firstName: String!) {}
```

it still doesn't work.

What would be the best way to do this?

-- EDIT --

I see the problem.  It is something to do with the following line in the EmployeeManager class:

```
var employeeManager: EmployeeManager = EmployeeManager()
```

If I do this in the AddClick, it works:

```
@IBAction func AddClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    var e = EmployeeManager()
    e.AddFirstName(firstName.text)
}
```

This line is meant to act like a singleton and provide app wide access to the EmployeeManager class.  Did I do this wrong?

```
var employeeManager: EmployeeManager = EmployeeManager()
```

Comment: Have you tried `func employeeManager.AddFirstName(firstName: String?)` and check within that function if firstName is a string and not nil?

Comment: I don't believe your `AddFirstName()` definition is like that. It must be `func AddFirstName(firstName: String) {` or such. Please paste your actual code.

Comment: Tried that but get the same error.  This is a compile time and not runtime error.

Comment: @rintaro I've updated the add method.  Right now, it is completely empty for simplicity.

Comment: I'm not saying about `}`. If you want to declare an instance method, `func employeeManager.AddFirstName(` should be `func AddFirstName(`. If what you want is *class* method it should be `class func AddFirstName(`.

Comment: @rintaro I see what you are saying.  That was a typo.  I've updated the code.

Comment: Hm...I can't duplicate the error in either Xcode 6.2 or 6.3 beta. It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @aganders3 Could you post your project to a Dropbox?  You might have the answer.

Comment: @4thSpace I just made a minimal test in a playground. Here it is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1521888/Etc/testStringArg.playground.zip

Comment: Thanks.  That definitely works.  I've tried removing the parameter all together but then get "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call".

Comment: Just posted an edit update to the OP.  Unfortunately, I can't create that scenario in a playground (use of undeclared type error).

Comment: Maybe using a pattern like this will help? https://github.com/hpique/SwiftSingleton

Comment: @aganders3 that pattern will work but I was trying to follow this pattern: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=war0gHL26ns.  Check at 5:07 and implementation at 25:16.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in my use of

```
var employeeManager: EmployeeManager = EmployeeManager()
```

Going with a Singleton pattern, which the above is really supposed to behave like, resolves this issue.

Comment: I think the reason that pattern worked in the tutorial video was that he never referenced the "singleton" instance within its own class definition. That is, his `addClick` method was handled by a separate class.

Comment: So is mine.  It's created from the drag/drop within IB.

Comment: Well, then I'm out of ideas! Seems odd, but maybe just chalk it up to the fact that Swift is still changing and maybe the tutorial is using a different version.

Comment: I'm thinking the same.  Thanks for all your help.  At least I think we have verified the technique from that video no longer works.  And the best way to go in this case is the Singleton.  But I'm going to post another question on Singletons in Swift in case there is something better.